# Web Apps install problem in 12.04 64bit installation

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, webapps

I just did:

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webapps/preview
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-preview
```

and get the following message:

```bash
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
state information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This
may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are
using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following
information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  unity-webapps-preview
: Depends: xul-ext-unity but it is not going to be installed
  Depends: xul-ext-websites-integration but it is not going to be installed
  Depends: xul-ext-webaccounts but it is not going to be installed 
      E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Missing dependencies, the error is telling you what is wrong and what is missing.

Comment: Can you tell me how I can fix that?

Comment: Install those packages, use `apt-get install -f`.

Comment: I just try `sudo apt-get install -f xul-ext-websites-integration` and get `Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xul-ext-websites-integration : Breaks: firefox (>= 15.+) but 16.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Answer (score 3):

I am having the same problem, I tried installing the dependent packages but it gave me this

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    xul-ext-websites-integration : Breaks: firefox (>= 15.+) but
    16.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
```

I read somewhere that removing firefox and then installing chromium solves the problem, havn't tried it yet as i like firefox

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 32bit

Comment: I read that too, but I can't remove firefox from my box, so this solution is not for me neither for those who want installed both browsers, firefox and chrome. Thanks for your reply.